# Extract Java Beans Information and Save to SQL Database

Tags: java, javabeans

It has been 20 years since I wrote any Java Code, and While I am willing to go down that path, I wanted to see if anyone knows of a tool, or product that will extract Java Bean information that can then be stored in a database?

Comment: Maybe Spring Data JPA is something for you? Spring is probably the hottest framework in Java right now and will serve as a good refresher after 20 years.

Comment: More appropriate place for such questions would be https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/